# Wrapping text within a multiple <select> list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give the user the ability to select multiple elements (which happen to be about a paragraph each).  The problem is that a standard select multiple in html is (as far as I can tell) a single line per choice.  This is a problem as the layout gets very screwy if I let the line go long.  Also, if I just truncate the line, the main gist of the text is lost.  Is there a way to get around this with javascript?  Is there an alternative that allows all of the text to be displayed and return the values back in a colon delimited list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could do this. The most straightforward would be to just put a checkbox next to each paragraph. The user can check the boxes next to the paragraphs of his choosing.

If you have a smoother interface in mind, you can extend that idea by hiding the checkboxes with CSS, then using JavaScript to <del>make the checkboxes selected when the corresponding paragraph is clicked and</del> highlight the paragraph (by applying a CSS class) to show it as selected. A framework like jQuery will streamline this process nicely.

**Edit:** Now that I think of it, as long as you put each paragraph in a `<label>` element you don't even need JavaScript to check/uncheck the hidden checkboxes; that will happen automatically as long as the label's `for` attribute is set correctly. All you need JavaScript for is to highlight/unhighlight the labels.

Here's a naive implementation using jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  input.hidden-checkbox { display: none; }
  label.multi-select { display: block; cursor: pointer; }
  label.checked { background-color: #ddd; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.hidden-checkbox').bind('change', function(e) {
      var checkBox = $(e.target),
          label = $('label[for=' + checkBox.attr('id') + ']');

      if(label) {
        if(checkBox.attr('checked')) {
          label.addClass('checked');
        } else {
          label.removeClass('checked');
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <input  type="checkbox" value="1"
          name="paragraph[]" id="paragraph-1"
          class="hidden-checkbox"/>
  <label for="paragraph-1" class="multi-select">Text of paragraph 1.
    As long as you want. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</label>

  <input  type="checkbox" value="2"
          name="paragraph[]" id="paragraph-2"
          class="hidden-checkbox" class="multi-select" />
  <label for="paragraph-2" class="multi-select">Paragraph 2's text.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</label>

  <!-- ...etc... -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for progressive enhancement. Would be pretty easy to implement even without a JS framework.