# can options in selects be more than one line?

Tags: html

I'm talking about your standard:

```
<select>
    <option>blah blah</option>
    <option>blah bl</option>
</select>
```

my problem is, for the dataset I must include in this dropdown, I've got a few outliers:

[image]

That's a distribution graph of the total occurrences (y-axis) of all character counts (x-axis) for the strings in the dropdown.

The average is only ~18.5 characters, but accommodating the 101 char string forces me to use a really small font.

Is there a way to wrap text inside a `<option></option>` ? I tried just dropping a `<br />` inside the middle of the string and that didn't validate.

Comment: Can you shorten the longest options using ellipsis?

Comment: @Simon - as a last resort, yes.

Comment: Can't be sure if this will help without seeing the data set, but perhaps the use of `<optgroup>` would let you shorten some of the entries by putting part of the option content in the `<optgroup>`. With that many entries in a select, it'd probably be user-friendly to use them regardless.

Comment: You can always use a third-party dropdown control.  There are many free ones available, and with jQuery, they are dead simple to use.  Also check into auto-complete libraries which pare down the visible options nicely for user-friendliness.

Comment: @steveax - there aren't that many displayed at once, as the dropdown is dependent upon a parent dropdown. However, for one particular selection on the parent dropdown you get the mega-option on the child dropdown.

Comment: that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787620/wrapping-text-within-a-multiple-select-list

Comment: I would second @mellamokb's suggestion of using an auto-complete "combobox" sort of approach. The jQuery UI version (they have a demo) works well, giving both the typical`select` functionality, as well as letting users type a few characters to get the option they want (especially helpful for power users of an app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, native `<select>` and `<option>` form controls offer very little control over how they can be styled, especially if cross-browser compatibility is a concern. If you want to be able to control things much better, your best bet is to have everything in a normal `<select>` box (for accessibility) and then to override it with a *fake* select box using JavaScript. I've had to do this in the past and the jQuery UI library worked well for me.

In your case, one possible UI that might would (if you go the JavaScript replace route) would be to use an ellipsis on the long elements, but then show their full text on `mouseover` and `focus` (it's early, so these might not be the correct events, but you get the idea).

Once you have JavaScript controlling a fake select box, there's really no end to what you can do for the UI behavior, but ultimately, if you need control, native form controls usually don't cut it.

Comment: I'd second that. Go with a custom drop-down list. I have liked: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ You have complete control over it then.    The selects seem to be fairly inflexible. Plus, there might be a bug with the latest version of Safari in trying to apply css styles to selects.